# Does anyone know of a good OpenLayers source implementation to support an ArcGIS Server FeatureServer service?

Tags: openlayers, arcgis-server

The OpenLayers folks gave us a good starting off point with https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-esri.html but it is lacking in at least one way.  If you modify that example by setting the initial zoom level to 0 the request for features will fail to return all of them.  Only one query will return results:

https://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Petroleum/KSFields/FeatureServer/0/query/?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22%3A-20037508.342789244%2C%22ymin%22%3A0%2C%22xmax%22%3A0%2C%22ymax%22%3A20037508.342789244%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%7D%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=102100&outFields=*&outSR=102100&callback=jQuery351038373015585341097_1629727417011&_=1629727417032

This URL will return 1000 features and the tileStrategy (or maybe VectorSource) has no idea that this is an indication of a partial result and happily marks that tile as fully loaded.

So my question is directed to anyone that as either solved or is aware of an existing solution to effectively render ArcGIS FeatureServer data on an OpenLayers map.

I have found one very bad solution:

```
map.on('moveend', () => {
  vectorSource.refresh();
});
```

It will clear the entire tile cache and re-query for all features.  I would like to limit the "refresh" to just those tile that represent 1000 features (or whatever represents the max feature count).

The beginnings of a solution may be to record all extents that return 1000 features and not even render them:

```
  if (1000 === features.length) {
    extentsToClear.push(extent);
  } else {
    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
  }
```

When the map extent changes, clear these extents:

```
map.on("moveend", () => {
  while (extentsToClear.length) {
    vectorSource.removeLoadedExtent(extentsToClear.pop());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, but not guaranteed way, would be to ensure that requests are always small by setting a `minZoom` on the strategy tilegrid.  So instead of one large request at level 9 there would be 4 smaller requests at level 10:

```
  strategy: tileStrategy(
    createXYZ({
      tileSize: 512,
      minZoom: 10
    })
  ),
```

The alternative, which would need more coding, would be to test `features.length` in the loader and if it is 1000 instead of returning success to divide the extent and try each of those again inside the loader (multiple fetches could be handled using `Promise.all`).

Comment: I like the minZoom idea!  I was unaware of that option.  The 4x split of the extent could get very expensive...imagine a FeatureService with 1 million features.  I was thinking a hybrid clusting solution might be out there.

Comment: This opens at zoom 7 and loads many small tiles instead of a few big ones https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-esri-forked-12pvq  Consequently you will see far more features than in the original example when it opened at the same level.

Comment: I like it but my preference is to instead reduce the tileSize.  For this sample I used a tile size of 64 (see it at https://codesandbox.io/embed/vector-esri-forked-wn2it?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).  But yes, modifying the createXYZ options seems to be the quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that blots out the areas that are returning an incomplete feature set and re-queries that area when the map changes.  A more advanced solution might wait until the zoom level exceeds the present one.  This at least give the user an impression of an incomplete result set.

[image]

Zoom in once more and the box drops away:

[image]

This was achieved by creating a placeholder feature:

```
  if (1000 === features.length) {
    extentsToClear.push(extent);
    const feature = makeFeature(extent);
    featuresToClear.push(feature);
    vectorSource.addFeatures([feature]);
  } else {
    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
  }
```

And clearing the feature and the problematic extent whenever the map extent change (a better solution would be to wait until the zoom level increases):

```
map.on("moveend", () => {
  while (extentsToClear.length) {
    vectorSource.removeLoadedExtent(extentsToClear.pop());
  }
  while (featuresToClear.length) {
    vectorSource.removeFeature(featuresToClear.pop());
  }
});
```

You can try it [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vector-esri-forked-wn2it?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).